# How to find number of bits used in address aliasing by the cpu?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-access

I am referring to this question and the top voted answer :-

[Why are elementwise additions much faster in separate loops than in a combined loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops)

My question is, is there an easy way of determining the number of bits (call it N) that the specific cpu uses for address aliasing for load/store?

Comment: Funny. Googling "partial address aliasing" turns up that question as the second result. I guess there isn't much literature about the topic.

Comment: Note that the address aliasing is particular to a cache, not a CPU. Most modern CPUs have at least two levels of cache. Furthermore, your question assumes that this is a constant. That's very much an implementation detail.

Comment: Yes it is an implementation detail. I'm looking for a test program that I can run on my CPU and use it to figure out N for that specific CPU and one specific cache level. Or maybe just some piece of documentation someplace that states that. Whichever is easier.

Answer (score 0):

At the OS level: no.  I'm not aware of any standard OS APIs (including anything in Linux or Win32) that give you any user-space visibility to CPU cache.

However, Intel provides some *great* tools for low-level performance analysis and optimization.  For example,

- Intel Performance Counter:
  http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/