# Sorting with just one loop. Help me with its efficiency

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have came up with a new sorting algorithm with just one do while loop in it, but i don't
know how to calculate the efficiency of it in best,average and worst case so please help me in calculating it.
The loop starts with i=1 and the end condition for while loop is i<=n-2 and some times the value of i increases in the loop and some times i value will be decremented based on some condition.

I think i will better understand if u illustrate through simple examples.
please help me............
Thank you in advance for those who help me.....

Comment: We can't really evaluate the complexity of an algorithm without knowing what the algorithm is. In particular code (or even pseudo code) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Unless you post the code you have, this looks like a "solve my homework assignment for me" request!

Comment: Who said one loop is always faster than two loops? [Shameless counterexample.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops)

Comment: Did you reinvent [Gnome sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort)?

Answer (score 2):

> some times i value will be decremented based on some condition

This vagueness makes it impossible to analyze. If the "condition" is always true and `i` is decremented to zero, then the loop runs forever. So based on what you say, the time complexity could be anything from `Theta(n)` to infinity.

The way to work out time complexity is to calculate (or put an upper bound on) the number of operations performed, as a function of `n`. "Operations" in the case of sorting usually means comparisons and copies/moves, but if your algorithm does anything unusual then of course that has to be included.

Comment: whenever i encounter i=0 i am incrementing i value