# Handing out addresses in a custom memory allocator w.r.t. cache conflicts

Tags: c, performance, memory-management, cpu-cache

I've spent my afternoon reading up on processor caches after reading about [the effect power of twos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops) can have on cache conflicts. Now I wish to apply this new knowledge to my memory allocator for multi-threaded programs. However, I don't fully understand it yet.

I was under the impression that processors *loved* powers of two, so my allocator rounds requested sizes to their next power of two and then slices pages into multiples of this size and hands them out. When a page is full, it simply maps a new page and slices it up the same way. This leads to very similar and predictable offsets into pages.

To what extent should I adapt my allocator to avoid this issue? For example, should I try to randomize addresses slightly or am I screwed for using powers of two in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try it, and benchmark the difference?

Comment: @SecurityMatt I have not benchmarked anything yet because I'm not confident on how to properly test it. However, given how the allocator operates, it *might* contribute to poor cache utilization. It might not even make sense to try to combat it at the allocator level. I don't know. :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd make your allocator assuming that caches don't exist, and then link some big programs to use it and test them. If the performance is good enough, congratulations, you're done. Otherwise, you can edit your code and you have a great reference implementation to benchmark against.

Answer (score 0):

Until you have uncontrovertible proof that *this* is performance critical, just leave it be. The extra complication will most probably not be worth it.

Everybody should read (and understand!) Bentley's "Writing efficient programs" (sadly out of print now, his ["Programming Pearls"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) contains a summary, and is well worth a read too).

- Before embarking on a code-optimization bout, make *sure* it is worth it. If the performance is adequate, there are better uses of your time. Yes, you have to measure first.
- Measure where the cost is being spent. Programmers are notoriously bad at guessing where the costs are
- The most performance gains come from restating the problem (sometimes it is enough to solve a problem that is faster to solve), then overall organization of the system, next better algorithms/data structures; and at the very, very end detail optimizations like the one considered here.
- Your friendly compiler, given a bit of prodding in the direction of "generate good code" will today generate *much* better code than an experienced assembly language programmer when given similar (full function scale) tasks. Most local source code reorganizations "for performance" are either moot (the compiler would have done so on its own) or deleterious (the compiler will recognize and rewrite the usual code sequences, unusual code can confuse it to do nothing or generate bad code).
- Programmer time (writing, debugging, maintaining) is much more valuable than a few microseconds of computer time here and there, except for extremely unusual circumstances. Write the simplest code that does the job, rework only if experience shows it is worthwile.

Comment: What you say is generally true and I would upvote it if it was specific to the question. I think the OP should receive more that the general "premature optimization" warning as an answer.

Comment: True, forgot about that. OP should take a hard look at the Linux kernel memory allocator(s), <http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelMemoryAllocation> should be a good starting point.