# Array allocation on HEAP (Separate allocation vs ... contiguous?)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, heap-memory

In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547993/5324086

The person has done allocation of arrays on HEAP in two ways:

```
int main(){
    const int n = 100000;

#ifdef ALLOCATE_SEPERATE
    double *a1 = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *b1 = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *c1 = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *d1 = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
#else
    double *a1 = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double) * 4);
    double *b1 = a1 + n;
    double *c1 = b1 + n;
    double *d1 = c1 + n;
#endif
}
```

What is the difference between the two ways of allocation?

Is the second method in else block allocating in a contiguous manner?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct.

Comment: yep. at least the virtual memory will be contiguous, not necessarily in  /dev/ram ... also what kind of weird architecture is this code for? o.0

Comment: @JoachimPileborg also, why has he done a multiply by 4?

Comment: @Spandan Because the code is allocating space for *4* buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(I am focusing on a Linux point of view; adapt it to your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and/or compiler implementation)</sup>

The code in your question has a C-like look and feel. Genuine C++ would use [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), that is in the non `ALLOCATE_SEPARATE` case something like

```
 double *a1 = new double[4*n];
 double *b1 = a1 + n;
```

and if the memory allocation failed you'll get a [std::bad_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception.

> What is the difference between the two ways of allocation?

The `ALLOCATE_SEPARATE` case is doing four calls to `malloc`. Notice that:

- every individual `malloc` could fail and you should check that, e.g. with

  ```
  double *a1 = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
  if (!a1) { perror("malloc a1"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
  ```

  assuming that you want some C code. And `malloc` *can* fail e.g. when the kernel is not able to give more virtual memory, e.g. because [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) failed, some limits have been reached (see [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)...), swap space has been exhausted (with memory overcommit being disabled), etc.... Read about [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) & [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), and the man pages of [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), notably its *NOTES* section.... BTW, your computer has *finite* resources, so they can be overflown. On a cheap laptop you won't be able to successfully `malloc`  ten terabytes of memory (and reliably use the memory zone) in 2015. Of course for `n = 100000` the `malloc`  will *usually* succeed.
- in practice `malloc` might fail if you ask for *a lot* of memory (gigabytes), but some operating systems have [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) (I personally dislike that feature and disable in on my Linux systems) and give you some pointer even if there is not enough space for the huge memory zone
- in the unlikely case `n * sizeof(double)` is overflowing `size_t`, disaster will happen.

The non-`ALLOCATE_SEPARATE` is asking for `malloc(n * sizeof(double) * 4)` and that could overflow with a smaller value of `n` (still very large in practice). The `* 4` is needed because we ask for enough space to fit four distinct non-[aliasing pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) and their non-overlapping memory zones.

> Is the second method in else block allocating in a contiguous manner?

Of course yes (and as I told that might overflow or fail for a smaller value of `n`, .e.g. when `n * sizeof(double) * 4` that is `n * 32` on a 32 bits Linux (i.e. Android) tablet is larger than e.g. 3 gigabytes, and probably even one gigabyte.

Actually, you should use C++11 [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and code:

```
#include <vector>
int main(){
   const int n = 100000;
   std::vector<double> vec(n);
```

the vector's data would sit in heap, and the destructor of `vec` would release it.

Of course, [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) data is allocated in the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (on Linux, probably using the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) -or sometimes `sbrk`- [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)).

Comment: If you want to manage the memory on a lower level (you don't always want vectors everywhere, they are troublesome for some types) you could (should?) use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/) class.

Comment: Why would malloc fail for a large memory request? Isn't it robust enough to handle such requests?

Comment: @Spandan: your laptop don't have ten terabytes of memory; so you cannot `malloc` that much

Comment: From: http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc `By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy. This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there is no guarantee that the memory really is available.`  You should test the returned pointer with `malloc_usable_size()` to ensure that you have the real space available.  Personally, I find this really stupid as it breaks a pretty basic and understandable precondition.  I have no idea what the linux ppl were smoking when they did that.