# Problem storing strings inside double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, c-strings

I've been doing this [code wars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58f5c63f1e26ecda7e000029) in which you have to take a string, and capitalize each letter, forming a Mexican wave-looking array of strings. For example, an input string like

`hello`

will result in `["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]`

I managed to complete it in JavaScript, and decided to attempt it in C. The actual code itself *is* working, as it prints the correct output, but the problem I am having is actually storing the string inside a double pointer.

This is my code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void wave(char *s, char **array);

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(6);
    strcpy(s, "hello");

    char **array = malloc(pow(strlen(s)+1, 2));

    wave(s, array);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        printf("s = %s\n", array[i]);
    }

    free(array);
    free(s);

    return 0;
}

void wave(char *s, char **array)
{
    char s2[strlen(s)+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }

    int array_index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        strcpy(s2, s);

        if (s[i] != ' ')
        {

            s2[i] = toupper(s2[i]); // Printing out `s2` here results in the correct output
            array[array_index++] = s2; // Adding it here works, but when trying to access it outside of this function, it gives the incorrect output
        }
    }
}
```

When printing the string inside the function, I get the following output (which is correct):

```
Hello
hEllo
heLlo
helLo
hellO
```

But when I try to print it out inside the `main()` function, I get the following:

```
s = hellO
s = hellO
s = hellO
s = hellO
s = hellO
```

It seems like it is adding/accessing only the last string in the array. I cannot understand why accessing the element inside the `wave()` function works, but accessing it outside of that function doesn't.

I've had this problem twice before, both in `C` and `C++`, and have been unable to solve it, and it is really annoying me.

Comment: What is char **array = malloc(pow(strlen(s), 2));?!

Comment: You're missing a NUL terminator for the copied strings (you're allocating `strlen` instead of `strlen + 1` for each string)... also, you should probably treat this as a `char *`, seeing as you are performing a single allocation - `buf + (strlen(s) + 1)` will mark the beginning of the second string.

Comment: @picklerick You are wrong. He needs to allocate only strlen pointers of the type char *.

Comment: @picklerick One more see its statement char **array = malloc(pow(strlen(s), 2)); And see the type of array.

Comment: @picklerick It is you who doesn not undersand the declaration. The declaration does not make any sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is there something wrong with the return type for `char **array = malloc(pow(strlen(s)+1, 2));`?

Comment: @AaronGarton This entirely does not make any sense. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left this as a comment, but since it might not be clear, I'll post my answer in code...

As stated in my comment, there's no point allocating a pointer array - on a 64 bit machine, that would be 6 pointers, each requiring 8 bytes to point at a 7 byte long data block - **a total of 104 bytes** (ignoring the added allocator padding per allocation).

Instead, **a single allocation could suffice, allocating 42 bytes** to contain all the "wave" strings and their NUL byte in a single block of memory (saving memory while improving locality).

```
int main(void) {
  /* Assuming string "hello" */
  const char *org = "hello";
  /* Calculate length only once and store value */
  const size_t len = strlen(org);
  const size_t len_with_nul = len + 1;
  /* Allocate `len` strings in a single allocation */
  char *buf = malloc(len * len_with_nul);
  /* Copy each string to it's place in the buffer */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    /* position in the buffer */
    char *pos = buf + (i * len_with_nul);
    /* copy the NUL as well */
    memcpy(pos, org, len_with_nul); 
    /* Wave... */
    pos[i] = toupper(pos[i]);
  }
  /* Print result */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char *pos = buf + (i * len_with_nul);
    printf("s = %s\n", pos);
  }
  /* Free buffer */
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT - Why is using a single memory block better?**:

In this case we allocate a single memory "block" (blob / slice). This offers a number of advantages:

- We perform a single allocation and deallocation instead of a larger number of allocations and deallocations.

  This improves speed by performing less actions.
- We also improve memory locality, [which minimizes CPU cache misses and improves performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126529/what-is-the-cost-of-an-l1-cache-miss).
- We use less memory.

  Each memory allocation comes with a price - we need a pointer to hold the memory address for the memory we allocated. A pointer "costs" 8 bytes on a 64bit machine and 4 bytes on a 32bit machine.

  By using a single allocation, we "pay" less.

  This is true even if we ignore the metadata attached to the memory block allocated (which requires memory from the memory allocator).

I should note that C doesn't really care about the contents of a memory block, **it's all zeros and ones**. The meaning given to these zeros and ones is left to the developer.

Even the `printf` function doesn't care about the contents of the memory it's reading - it simply reads the memory according to the formatting it was instructed to follow by the developer (the `%s` informs the function that the memory relates to a NUL terminated string).

There are some concerns about memory alignment which are CPU and system specific - but these don't apply to single byte strings. They apply to multi-byte types (such as `short`, `int`, and `long`). So we don't need to worry about them in this example.

In this sense, it basically means that **the developer is free to manage the memory and the contents as they see fit** (putting aside memory alignment).

This is not to say that it's always better to allocate a single block of memory (if you need to use `realloc`, you might prefer smaller chunks)... but usually a single block of memory is better.

Comment: @AaronGarton - you're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer. It's the common way to say "thank you" on SO :)

Comment: accepted your answer, because it fixed my problem :D but I don't think one long string is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: @AaronGarton - I edited the answer to answer the question in your comment. I hope you will see that, in this specific case, using "one long string" is actually better. If the strings had to be reallocated during runtime, it might be a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is unclear why you are allocating dynamically memory for the string literal "hello".

```
char *s = malloc(6);
strcpy(s, "hello");
```

It does not make any sense.

Just write

```
const char *s = "hello";
```

This declaration

```
char **array = malloc(pow(strlen(s), 2));
```

also does not make sense. What you need is the following.

```
size_t n = strlen( s );

char **array = malloc( n * sizeof( char * ) );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    array[i] = malloc( n + 1 );
}
```

The function `wave` can be defined the following way

```
void wave( const char *s, char **array )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        strcpy( array[i], s );
        array[i][i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )s[i] );
    }
}
```

and then in main after the function call

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    puts( array[i] );
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( array[i] );
free( array );
```

Here is the full program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void wave( const char *s, char **array )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        strcpy( array[i], s );
        array[i][i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )s[i] );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "hello";
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char **array = malloc( n * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = malloc( n + 1 );
    }

    wave( s, array );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        puts( array[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( array[i] );
    free( array );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello
hEllo
heLlo
helLo
hellO
```

Comment: I upvoted the answer (even if [I would have avoided the multiple allocation sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525189/4025095))... however: I would recommend to store the result for `strlen` in a variable. It's true that the compiler usually performs the optimization, but still, it's good practice to avoid repeated function calls when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works perfectly! I was a little confused about how to do the allocation for a double pointer. And as for using `size_t`, is it always better to use `size_t` over `int`?

Comment: @AaronGarton the return type of the function strlen is size_t. An object of the type int can be too small to hold any value of an object of the type size_t.